# Mac OS X Server on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, mac-osx-server

I'm thinking of making a dynamic HTTP Live streaming server, and I'm going to need a lot of CPU power that can transcode and segment the files on demand, so naturally I thought of EC2.

I've been researching for awhile, and it looks like I can't find the HTTP Live Streaming tools that Apple provides for Linux that also can encrypt the stream.

Is it possible (legal?) to run instances of Mac OS X server on EC2? I also had the idea of running the Darwin core (much cheaper than buying all those OS X licenses...), but I haven't checked whether OS X binaries run on Darwin Core.

I'd be glad if anyone has had a similar problem shared their experiences! Thanks in advance.

Comment: EC2 couldn't run it anyway, legally and physically not possible.

Comment: @tim why not? ec2 can run virtual box, virtual box can run osx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not legal. You are allowed to run it on Apple hardware *only*, and in case of 10.5/10.6 server and 10.7 virtualized on Appple hardware.

Edit: This is valid for MacOS. I have no idea about the Darwin Core, never used it at all outside the main product.

Comment: Also, I have no real clue about this streaming stuff, but there is an open source component in form of the Darwin Streaming server at http://dss.macosforge.org/. Maybe this helps you?